# Struts 2 jQuery action returning entire form on success

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a JSP which uses Struts 2 jQuery tags.

The form is :

```xml
<s:form data-role="content" class="center-btn" id="sortForm"
            theme="simple">
<s:textfield name="item" id="item"/>
<s:textfield name="acc" id="acc"/>
</s:form>
```

Have a action:

```java
@Action(value = "getLPNDetails", results = {
            @Result(name = SUCCESS, type = JSON, params = { "ignoreHierarchy", "false", "includeProperties",
                    "sortForm\\..*,actionMessages\\[\\d+\\], fieldErrors\\[\\d+\\], actionErrors\\[\\d+\\]" }),
            @Result(name = INPUT, location = "sortMUIDMobile.jsp", params = { "ignoreHierarchy", "false",
                    "includeProperties",
                    "url\\..*, actionMessages\\[\\d+\\], fieldErrors\\[\\d+\\], actionErrors\\[\\d+\\]" }),
            @Result(name = ERROR, location = "sortMUIDMobile.jsp", params = { "ignoreHierarchy", "false",
                    "includeProperties",
                    "sortForm\\..*, actionMessages\\[\\d+\\], fieldErrors\\[\\d+\\], actionErrors\\[\\d+\\]" }) })
    public String getLPNDetails() {
}
```

Which I am calling from :

```js
function lpnFilter() {
                var param = $('#sortForm').serialize();
                //var jsonValidationParam = "&struts.enableJSONValidation=true";
                //param = param + jsonValidationParam;
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'getLPNDetails',
                    data : param,
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        //alert(data.lpn);

                    },
                    async : false
                });
                //$('#lpnDetails').show();
            }
```

Now :

```java
@Action(value = "getLPNDetails", results = {
                @Result(name = SUCCESS, type = JSON, params = { "ignoreHierarchy", "false", "includeProperties",
                        "sortForm\\..*,actionMessages\\[\\d+\\], fieldErrors\\[\\d+\\], actionErrors\\[\\d+\\]" }),
```

Is not returning all the values of the form. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration via annotation that returns `json` type result should have parameter `"includeProperties", "sortForm\..*`. Everything else is not required, so it could be removed from the question.

Now you want to return `sortForm` object from the action. Make sure the action bean is on `top` of the valuestack and contains getters and setters for `sortForm` and getters and setters for its properties.

The form should bind its properties to the `sortForm` object.

```xml
<s:form data-role="content" class="center-btn" id="sortForm"
            theme="simple">
<s:textfield name="sortForm.item" id="item"/>
<s:textfield name="sortForm.acc" id="acc"/>
</s:form>
```

---

Make sure the [struts2-json-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts2-json-plugin) is on the classpath and parent package is a descendant of the `json-default`. The parent package could be set by `@ParentPackage` annotation or use default parent package xml constant. This is necessary to `json` result to return JSON object serialized from the action bean's properties.

```
@Result(type="json", params = {"includeProperties", "^sortForm\\..*"})
```

---

This regex expression match every property of the `sortform` object, but you only need two properties.

```
@Result(type="json", params = {"includeProperties", "^sortForm\\.item, ^sortForm\\.acc"})
```